# Any way to shorten this JavaScript code for a page animation / other ways to achieve the same result?

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a website and need a html page which does not refresh but still loads different types of content when the navigation button is pressed. I am new to JavaScript, but have created a JS code for a margin animation. Is there a better way so that there is either just 1 function or another way (even involving CSS and not Javascript only, in terms of moving things). Any help would be appreciated.

```js
var hc = document.getElementById("home_content");
var sc = document.getElementById("summary_content");
var muc = document.getElementById("music_content");
var mec = document.getElementById("members_content");
var ne = document.getElementById("news_content");
var currentlyon = document.getElementById("currentlyon");

window.onload = function() {
  hc.style.marginLeft = "1%";
}

document.getElementById("home_nav").addEventListener("click", function() {
  currentlyon.style.left = "0%";
  hc.style.marginLeft = "1%";
  sc.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
  muc.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
  mec.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
  ne.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
})
document.getElementById("summary_nav").addEventListener("click", function() {
  currentlyon.style.left = "20%";
  hc.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
  sc.style.marginLeft = "1%";
  muc.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
  mec.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
  ne.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
})

document.getElementById("music_nav").addEventListener("click", function() {
  currentlyon.style.left = "40%";
  hc.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
  sc.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
  muc.style.marginLeft = "1%";
  mec.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
  ne.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
})
document.getElementById("members_nav").addEventListener("click", function() {
  currentlyon.style.left = "60%";
  hc.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
  sc.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
  muc.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
  mec.style.marginLeft = "1%";
  ne.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
})
document.getElementById("news_nav").addEventListener("click", function() {
  currentlyon.style.left = "80%";
  hc.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
  sc.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
  muc.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
  mec.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
  ne.style.marginLeft = "1%";
})
```

```css
#home_content,
#summary_content,
#music_content,
#members_content,
#news_content {
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: absolute
}

.page_button
{
  cursor: pointer
}

.page_button:hover
{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="button_container">
    <ul>
      <canvas id="currentlyon"></canvas>
      <li id="home_nav" class="page_button">Home</li>
      <li id="summary_nav" title="Summary" class="page_button">Summary</li>
      <li id="music_nav" title="Music" class="page_button">Music</li>
      <li id="members_nav" title="Members" class="page_button">Members</li>
      <li id="news_nav" title="News" class="page_button">News</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="content">
  <div id="home_content">
    <p> 123 </p>
  </div>
  <div id="summary_content">
    <p> 456 </p>
  </div>
  <div id="music_content">
    <p> abc </p>
  </div>
  <div id="members_content">
    <p> def </p>
  </div>
  <div id="news_content">
    <p> ghi </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mhmm so you're basically asking us to rewrite your whole code using a better logic to shorten it?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy just shortening the Javascript part or proposing a new way using CSS only. I would appreciate code, but directions are fine as well.

Comment: Head over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: 1. UL>canvas is not valid HTML 2. addEventListeners to all LIs and in that test that `document.querySelectorAll("#content div").forEach(function(div) { div.style.marginLeft = div.id == clicked div) ? "1%" : "-100%" })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a single function that takes those values as parameters.

```
function addListener(item, currentL, hcL, scL, mucL, mecL, neL) {
    document.getElementById(item).addEventListener('click', function() {
        currentlyon.style.left = currentL;
        hc.style.marginLeft = hcL + '%';
        sc.style.marginLeft = scL + '%';
        muc.style.marginLeft = mucL + '%';
        mec.style.marginLeft = mecL + '%';
        ne.style.marginLeft = neL + '%';
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call it by:

```
addListener('home_nav', 0, 1, -100, -100, -100, -100);
addListener('summary_nav', -20, -100, 1, -100, -100, -100);
addListener('music_nav', 40, -100, -100, 1, -100, -100);
addListener('members_nav', 60, -100, -100, -100, 1, -100);
addListener('news_nav', 80, -100, -100, -100, -100, 1);
```

See, that is a 50% reduction in your scripting. If you repeat the same code over and over and over, you should probably make it a function.

Comment: It ended up working by adding quotation marks to the percentage signs as it needs to recognize it as a string. It was way more than a 50% reduction, thanks a lot.

Comment: @TorekiTarou Whoops, added those quotes in. Anywho, glad it helped :) Remember, more than once, make a function.